# Angular drop and focus events are triggered both

Tags: javascript, angular, event-handling, dom-events

I am using Angular 10 and registered a `drop` event on my `AppComponent`.

The same component also has a `focus` event, and when dragging a directory onto the BrowserWindow, both events are triggered.

Is there any way to distinguish exclusively a `drop` or a `focus` event?

```
@HostListener("window:focus", ["$event"])
onFocus(event: any): void {
    console.log("window:focus");
}

@HostListener("drop", ["$event"])
onDrop($event: any) {
    console.log("drop");
}
```

**Output:**

```
focus <-- 1: shouldn't happen on drop
focus <-- 2: shouldn't happen on drop
drop
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
focusDet: boolean = false;
```

...

```
@HostListener("drop", ["$event"])
onDrop($event: any) {
    this.focusDet = true;
    console.log("drop");
}

@HostListener("window:focus", ["$event"])
onFocus(event: any): void {
    if(!this.focusDet){
      console.log("window:focus");            
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking the same, but is this the "official" workaround?